# How to get data from anchor tag click event Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

Hay in my angular project, have search input box. In here i want to get id, when click the anchor tag. I will try to put click function to anchor tag, but it's did not work. Can you help me.

Angular 7 cli

#### Component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="search">
    <div class="input">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Select Pharamacy</label>
      <input name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm">
      <ul class="results">
        <li *ngFor="let data of pharmacyData | filterService : searchText; let i = index">

          <a (click)="selectedPharmacy(data.pharmacyId)"> {{data.pharmacyName}} </a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerService } from 'src/app/server.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-add-pharmacy',
  templateUrl: './admin-add-pharmacy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-add-pharmacy.component.css']
})
export class AdminAddPharmacyComponent implements OnInit {



 pharmacyData : any;

  constructor(private serverService : ServerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serverService.getAllPharmacyData().subscribe(
      (response:Response)=>{ 
        this.pharmacyData = response;    
        console.log(this.pharmacyData); 
      } 
    ); 
  } 

  selectedPharmacy(pharmacyId:any){
    console.log(pharmacyId);
  }

}
```

#### Console.log

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {pharmacyId: 27, pharmacyName: "Medi"}
1: {pharmacyId: 28, pharmacyName: "Medi 2"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: code is correct could you provide what error are you getting.

Comment: did not have any error. But as well as did not have alert.  I don't know why.

Comment: try `console.log()` if it's printing the pharmacyId or not

Comment: can you post the entire component.ts please. Also, try stopping and restarting your app.

Comment: @Jacques i added to code.

Comment: @skdroid I will try `console.log` but did not have any result.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? A stackblitz would help.

Comment: Can you add what is logged when you console.log this.pharmacyData?

Comment: @Jacques did not have any result friend.

Comment: @ThevinMalaka. To clarify, I'm asking about the console log in your ngOnInit method

Comment: @Jacques oh sorry.  It's `(2) [{…}, {…}]`

Comment: @ThevinMalaka. ....... I need to see what's in the objects. Paste what is returned from your request in your answer.

Comment: @Jacques i did..

Comment: Works just fine... https://angular-4swwue.stackblitz.io

Comment: ooooh... then i think misatek had in css file.. i will add css can you help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193771/discussion-between-thevin-malaka-and-jacques).